# css for displaying products in different size div like a pattern

Tags: jquery, css, html, plugins, size

[image]

Hi, I want to display my products like shown in this image.
Don't understand that how to apply size differently to each div that contains product info.

Is there any css or jquery plugin that can do this for me by applying in my aspx page.

please help me out or show me some work around for this.

Comment: Those are probably different columns, and height isn't specified at all for the individual items in the columns. Do the items line up evenly at the bottom? That would be the tricky part, but it's not clear whether that is part of the requirement.

Comment: yes .. items eventually lineup in bottom also according to the upper div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what screenshot you have provided, I assume you are looking for something like [THIS](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html).

It is a jQuery plugin for creating the kind of layout that you have mentioned in the screenshot. It comes with an organization and developer license.

If you want to start off with, you can also refer [THIS](http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenGridPortfolioTemplate/)

Hope this Helps.

Comment: yes thanks.. i ll give it a try.u know is there a ready made css that need to be applied for this ?

Comment: Both are ready made. You have to put your images, etc to make it work. That will not be a big effort than finding the CSS. Right?

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your purpose - @SachinTrivedi

Comment: yes but i didnt get you. how can i integrate it in my web app. can u explain me bit about what u said - "You have to put your images, etc to make it work" ?

Comment: Include everything in your project folder in the hierarchy mentioned. - @SachinTrivedi

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wtfdiary.com/2012/08/6-amazing-jquery-plugins-to-design.html

Here is the link which gives some cool plugins for layouts. Enjoy...